# Top Users view for the new site?

Tags: feature-request, support

I got in the habit of checking the [mathematica Top Users page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mathematica/topusers) on StackOverflow.  (Yes, competition can be fun.)  Is there a way to get a similar view on the new site that applies to all posts?

I am aware of [the Users page](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users) but it is not the same, and does not show vote totals for example.

Answer (score 5):

[On Area51 there's a user list sorted both based on reputation and how active people are.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37304/mathematica)

Comment: Apparently I spend too much time here ...

Comment: And I though *I* was bad.

Comment: I think the Area 51 "most active" metric is just (number of questions) + (number of answers)

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is to use custom SQL queries to query the data dump at data.stackexchange.com and calculate only upvotes. However, this is possible only after we graduate, which is when the data dumps become available.

In the meantime, you can use the API and run it as often as you'd like (upto 300 calls/day) from the comfort of your Frontend. It only needs a minor modification to [Sjoerd's example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5745783) (specifically, get the top 20 users for this *site* instead of a *particular tag* as in the example)

However, re: your feature request, I do not think this is a feature worth an SE developer's time. It's a very specific request for only *this* site, solely to stick to old habits, and will not enhance the experience of the site for most people. Hence, I vote **no**.

Comment: "and will not enhance the experience of the site for most people. Hence, I vote no."  Mine is the only experience that counts dang it! ;-)  Really, nobody else liked that leaderboard?

Comment: By the way, this answer leaves me with a dilemma: I want to vote up for the suggestion, and to vote down for "I vote no" therefore I did not vote at all.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I liked the leaderboard. I even made a screendump when, at one point in time, I achieved the no.3 position in the all-time section ;-)