# How to get annual Reputation statistics/trends

Tags: feature-request, data-dump

Is there an API or data-dump or an existing report that has anonymous data/information on *Reputation* over the year.  Things like rates of earned reputation over time with individual highest rates per unit of time. Stats on new users' and existing users rates of reputation. The distribution of reputation among users.  And so on.

Is there a way we can get this data to investigate these sorts of things.

Comment: You are aware of [this one](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/177/quarter/mathematica/2015-10-01/19542#19542), aren't you?

Comment: @Karsten7. No. Not until now. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

There are some nice QnAs going on here

[Statistics of the site](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289/statistics-of-the-site?rq=1)

[How are we doing? (Post your favorite stats!)](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301/how-are-we-doing-post-your-favorite-stats?lq=1)

[Extracting values from nested rules in JSON data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3111/extracting-values-from-nested-rules-in-json-data)

[Fetching data from HTML source](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3387/fetching-data-from-html-source)

[Top Users view for the new site?](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188/top-users-view-for-the-new-site/191#191)

[Toward Mathematica.Stackexchange analytics](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/toward-mathematica-stackexchange-analytics/1188)

[How do I access the StackOverflow API from Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745298/how-do-i-access-the-stackoverflow-api-from-mathematica/5745783#5745783)

or better: the 2.1 API version:

[Getting Mathematica.SE reputation data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13705/getting-mathematica-se-reputation-data)

But the best is here:

[StackExchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/)

just go to "Queries" and have fun.